# Use segue or some other method to show uiviewcontroller to create a new row for uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a uitableview and in the navigation bar I have a + button that is intended to allow the user to go to an editable version of the uiviewcontroller of the items in the tableview and let them create a new "record".  I had the + button setup to do a segue to the uiviewcontroller much like you do when simply viewing the detail of one of the "records" in the tableview list.  I am trying to understand if this is technique is ok or should I be showing the uiviewcontroller in a different way for the users to create the new data, such as modal or simply programmatically showing the uiviewcontroller instead of using a seque.  Thanks. I hope I made sense.

Comment: Anyone with any questions or more ideas?  I am concerned I may not be doing this the best way.  The + button does segue to uiviewcontroller and in prepareforsegue I indicate this is creation so when uiviewcontroller loads I add save button in navbar. The user enters data and hits save button and I write the data out to a json file and relaod tableview when user hit back button. This all seems to work but I was worried I shouldn't be using a segue to allow a user to create new data and that it should be a modal programmatic display of the uiviewcontroller and that was my main concern.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your new object in prepareForSegue, and set it on the destination controller's property. Whether or not that makes sense depends on your app's logic and flow; there's nothing wrong with it technically. One thing to be aware of is if the user opts out during the process, like, they back nav out, which leaves you with an inserted object that's junk. (assuming it's some sort of NSManagedObject, of course) so you'd probably want to handle that scenario nicely to prevent the blank row in your previous table view. You could also do it modally, and either way, you could just create the object upon save in your destination controller, thereby preventing the blank thing. But then, you might have to do some additional work to get the original controller a reference to this new object. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well what I did so far is the + button does segue to the uiviewcontroller and in prepareforsegue I know that it is for creation so when uiviewcontroller loads I put a save button in navbar.  The users enters data and hits the save button and I write the data out to a json file and then will relaod the tableview when users uses back button to go back.  This all seems to work ok but I was worried I shouldn't be using a segue to allow a user to create new data and that it should be a modal programmatic display of the uiviewcontroller and that was my main concern.